# How to flag content and block user with app that manages Facebook content? rejected by iTunes store because of safety guidelines

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

We created a video sharing app with unity, crazy right, but we did it. Not to give any IP away, the app allows users to upload videos to a public page. unfortunately apple rejected our app and this is there response.

**From Apple**
**Guideline 1.2 - Safety**

**Your app enables the display of user-generated content but does not have the proper precautions in place.**

**Next Steps**

**To resolve this issue, please revise your app to implement all of the following precautions:**

**- Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content or abusive users**

**- A method for filtering objectionable content**

**- A mechanism for users to flag objectionable content**

**- A mechanism for users to block abusive users**

**- The developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content and ejecting the user who provided the offending content**

So i asked them to call me because i don't understand why i should have built in precautions if Facebook already has a team that does this, the content is saved on a Facebook public page. Long story short the apple agent told me that it is my responsibility to do so. Who am i to argue with apple right? **So off to Facebook developer site i went and i can't find anything in the reference that will allow me to do so.** which makes now sense because why would i want to block someone on my app but on Facebook side you would still be harassed by said person right?

I also went looking for apps that manage Facebook content and they seem to be able to do it. here is the image and I'm trying to block my friend. this app is called **Friendly** if anyone wanted to know [image]

**Can anyone please assist or at least point me into the right direction. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: [That guy needs to charge his phone](https://xkcd.com/1373/).

Comment: @Draco18s LOL! someone on the Facebook developer page got back to me, check his reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Christoph Broeckmann on the Facebook Developer community page wrote this as a reply to the same question;

> There is no API to unfriend or block users. Any 3rd-party app you see
>   doing this is likely achieving this in a non-allowed way.
>
> Those guidelines from Apple primarily apply to stuff that happens
>   inside your app - if you display content within your app, then you
>   need to provide the user with ways to report it, block it, or block
>   the app user that created the content - all within your app. They can
>   hardly demand that your app removes friendships between users on
>   totally different platforms.
>
> Maybe they did not understand correctly that you do not show content
>   within the app itself. But if they did understand what your app does
>   correctly. and still think those rules should apply - then there is
>   little you can do about that.

so i think I'm going to build it into my own app and upload to apple. Thanks peeps!